# How to Implement slider button

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton

I'm talking about the "slide to unlock" button on iPhone. Any ideas how to go about implementing one in my own iPhone app? I don't see it as a control in IB?can any one suggest me?Thank You in advance...

Comment: This will help you.
Refer this link.... [http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-slider-control-uislider-control-tutorial/](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-slider-control-uislider-control-tutorial/)

Comment: thank u but i am looking for slider button not uislider controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these posts

[UISlider, slide to unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816891/uislider-slide-to-unlock)

[Slider which helps to unlock the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236998/slider-which-helps-to-unlock-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be such a good idea...

http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/slide-to-unlock-patented-20100818/

Comment: Apple's patent only covers the sliding gesture to unlock a device. I'm quite sure it's safe to replicate it for purposes other than that.