# Create slider similar to the unlock slider of the iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, uigesturerecognizer, slide

i read some questions here about UIGestureRecognizer but i am not sure how to accomplish the following task:

I would like to create something like the unlock slider of the iphone, but sliding a button around a circle. In this case i don´t need to look into the UIGestureRecognizer class, do i? I need an animation class or something...If you gave me some key-words to start with i would be really happy :)

maxi

Comment: Is not his similar to this [old post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236998/slider-which-helps-to-unlock-the-iphone

Answer (score 1):

You might try this page as a starting point

http://denizdemir.com/2011/03/07/animated-slider-iphones-cool-first-impression/

To do the circle version will involve a fair bit more work I'd say as not only do you need to read the circle gesture you also need your lock to move around the circle...

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/detecting-circle-gesture.html

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/13494-Messing-around-with-gestures

Could be there is a far simpler way to do this now but I'm not aware of it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:

> slide to unlock" clone from the iPhone's lockscreen using only public
>   APIs

https://github.com/iosdeveloper/SlideToCancel